# animate constraint swift fit all screen

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I am a beginner in constraint and recently i started working on animation, i was targeting iPhone 6s plus. Its all about moving balls from certain Y point to another..

```
  func animateBall(){
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0000001, options : [.CurveEaseInOut, .TransitionCurlDown,] , animations: {

        self.ball1.frame.origin.y = 121.0
        self.ball2.frame.origin.y = 175.0
        self.ball3.frame.origin.y = 340.0
        self.ball4.frame.origin.y = 394.0
        self.ball5.frame.origin.y = 447.0
        self.ball6.frame.origin.y = 502.0
        self.ball7.frame.origin.y = 555.0
        self.ball8.frame.origin.y = 585.0
        self.ball9.frame.origin.y = 68.0

        //
        //            }
        //

        } ,completion :{(finished:Bool) in
            // the code you put here will be compiled once the animation finishes
            self.restoreToNormalBalls()


    })
}



 func restoreToNormalBalls (){

    self.ball1.frame.origin.y = 68
    self.ball2.frame.origin.y = 121
    self.ball3.frame.origin.y = 175
    self.ball4.frame.origin.y = 340
    self.ball5.frame.origin.y = 394
    self.ball6.frame.origin.y = 447
    self.ball7.frame.origin.y = 502
    self.ball8.frame.origin.y = 555
    self.ball9.frame.origin.y = 15

}
```

I have made the constraints to fit on all screens but when i tap to animate, it works only for 6s Plus . Any help make the animation works on all screens ? 
Thanks

Comment: If you're using autolayout, you should animate constraints constants instead of frame

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) , any example on how to animate constraints constants from point to another ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using autolayout, you should animate constraints constants instead of frame:

```
func animateBall() {

    ball1Constraint.constant = 121.0;
    ball2Constraint.constant = 175.0;

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0000001, options : [.CurveEaseInOut, .TransitionCurlDown,] , animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded() // called on parent view

    } ,completion :{ (finished:Bool) in

        // the code you put here will be compiled once the animation finishes
        self.restoreToNormalBalls() // remember to modify this implementation method using constraints too
    })
}
```

- ball1Constraint & ball2Constraint are constraints connected as @IBOutlet from your Storyboard/Xib file

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @lubilis,

First of all add constraint for top space from ball to upper edge of it's container view.
Then make that constraint as `@IBOutlet`, let's say `outletedConstraintBall1`.
Then while animating, do like:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0000001, options : [.CurveEaseInOut, .TransitionCurlDown,] , animations: {

    outletedConstraintBall1.constant = 121
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
})
```

And for resetting it's position:

```
restoreToNormalBalls() {
     outletedConstraintBall1.constant = 68
}
```